Error: Illegal instruction (core dumped) on bench new-site Frappe ERPNext
I am following the Guide to install ERPNext below
https://discuss.frappe.io/t/guide-how-to-install-erpnext-v15-on-linux-ubuntu-step-by-step-instructions/111706
I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
On executing the command
 bench new-site --verbose site1.local

I get the below error
MySQL root password:
Created user _b533f5fdd65aaf8c
Created database _b533f5fdd65aaf8c
Granted privileges to user _b533f5fdd65aaf8c and database _b533f5fdd65aaf8c
Starting database import...
Imported from database /home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/database/mariadb/framework_mariadb.sql
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

I have added the settings below in my.cnf
my.cnf
Please advise on next steps I can take to resolve this.
I am trying to install ERPNext on Ubuntu.
